# Toolbar disappear in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to setup a toolbar in a RelativeLayout which has a listview inside. The problem is that as soon as I put two elements in the list this is the result:
[image]

The menu options disappear too. This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="26dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

change the following line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
```

to

```
android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
```

The plus sign is for creation of a new resource, when we need to reference an already created one ie (created by android:id="@+id/x") we should not use the + or it will not be referenced properly

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: try adding alignParentTop true to your toolbar

Comment: Good spot  .. and @Fabio make sure u change both place.. and also make sure your toolbar isnt **black**

Comment: yea check the style

Comment: also if it is inside an acitivity without no action bar theme, check if you are actually setting the toolbar to be shown

Comment: @SantanuSur the toolbar is black, why it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

just change the `android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"` of Listview into `android:layout_below="@+id/textList"`

Answer (score 0):

try this code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4WTE.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="26dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textList"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```